# How to run calcuation until the value has no decimals in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA but i would like to create a VBA script that can run a calculation until the answer has no decimals. (NOTE: rounding is not what I am after though)

For instance:
I would like to generate 3-digit number that can be divided by a constant number, 17. However, I do not know the combinations. Therefore I scripted cell A1 to C1 with random function between 0-9.

- A1:C1 contains random numbers
- A3 has a formula of "=sum(A1:C1) / 17"
- *17 is a constant number

If I want the calculation in cell A3 to run until the combination of numbers in A1:C1 that can be divided by constant number 17 in full; which there are no decimals.  (e.g. 170 / 17 = 10 which has no decimals. So, the value displayed in cell A1 to C1 would be 1, 7, 0; which is the answer)

Is it possible to create a VBA script to perform this?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like an ill-posed question. If you are doing floating-point calculations then your computed number might well have a decimal even if, mathematically, it shouldn't. What if the computed number is 10.00000001 or 9.999999999? Either do your calculations so that all numbers are always integers (and strive for a remainder to be 0), or introduce an error tolerance. As it is, it sounds like you are headed for an infinite loop.

Comment: This seems like a very strange way of solving (what I assume is) your problem.  There are only 52 3-digit numbers exactly divisible by 17.  Either list them all and pick one at random from the list; or pick a random integer between 6 and 58 and multiply that by 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Do
        Range("A1").Value = .RandBetween(1, 100)
        Range("B1").Value = .RandBetween(1, 100)
        Range("C1").Value = .RandBetween(1, 100)
        If Range("A3").Value Mod 17 = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes that cell **A3** contains:

```
=SUM(A1:C1)
```

rather than your formula.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you want only single digits in **A1** through **C1**, then put this formula in **A3**:

```
=A1*100+B1*10+C1
```

and use this macro:

```
Sub dural2()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Do
        Range("A1").Value = .RandBetween(1, 9)
        Range("B1").Value = .RandBetween(0, 9)
        Range("C1").Value = .RandBetween(0, 9)
        If Range("A3").Value Mod 17 = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes correct. I only want single digit in A1 through C1. 
Your formula works!! 

Although my actual situation is slightly more complicated than the one i have illustrated, it does its job brilliantly. Much appreciated for your effort! 

Many thanks.

Having said so, I am thinking if there is another way to make the code slightly less clumsy. Because the calculation I am working on is 11-digit number. :)

Comment: @DChain  You are quite welcome !  create a new Post and we will assis with the 11-digit problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run this Macro

```
Sub Macro()
    Do Until Range("A3") = 17
        Range("C1").Value = Int((100 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
        Range("B1").Value = Int((100 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
        Range("A1").Value = Int((100 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

        Range("A3") = (Range("A1") + Range("B1") + Range("C1")) / 17
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @DChain do you want only single digit numbers in cells A1, B1, C1. so you have a random range of 0 - 999? if so you will need to concatenate them.

Comment: I actually want single digit number in cell A1 to C1. the rand function i place in the cell is "Randbetween(0,9)". 

How to concatenate them in your formula, just wondering? 
Would love to learn more :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From @aucuparia's comment, you could pick a random integer in the range the results in a three digit number when multiplied by 17, multiply it, and get a "random" three digit number that's divisible by 17.

This code takes a divisor (17 in your case, but it can be integer). It determines the smallest number that when multiplied by the divisor results in a three digit number (lLower) and does the same for the largest number. Then it picks a random integer between those two numbers, multiplies it by 17, and returns the product.

```
Function RandomDivisible(ByVal lDivisor As Long) As Double

    Dim lLower As Long, lUpper As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lLower = Round(100 / lDivisor + 0.4999, 0)
    lUpper = Round(1000 / lDivisor - 0.4999, 0)

    RandomDivisible = Int((lUpper - lLower + 1) * Rnd + lLower) * lDivisor

End Function
```

Use as

```
=RandomDivisible(17)
```

Comment: Thank you sir but Round is to round up the decimals to integer, do i understand it correctly?

If so, it does not fit the work I am trying to achieve. 
I do have to thank you for providing this solution as it can be useful for other work I will be doing :)

Much appreciated.